# Looping entites and getting top 10 of each entity in Power Query / DAX / Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a requirement like.,

One Source and 10 entites 
I need each entites 10 runs data .

example like.,

```
     Source1  Entity1 ( top 10 )
     Source1  Entity2  ( top 10)
     ....
     ...
     Source1  Entity10 ( top 10)
```

I was trying in Power BI to get this done. I have whole of data with 200 records but when I sort with each entity with top 10 I must be able to get only 100 records.
Any help on how can I do this in DAX or Power Query

Thnanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, you can group on Entity with operator "All Rows", add a custom step ("Max10Runs"  below) to select the top 10 and then expand the column with nested tables (only field "Runs").

```
let
    Source = Source,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Entity"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table}}),
    Max10Runs = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"AllData", each Table.MaxN(_, each [Runs], 10)}}),
    #"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Max10Runs, "AllData", {"Runs"}, {"Runs"})
in
    #"Expanded AllData"
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind time for my Question

Comment: Could you please ellobrate a more on steps to run .., I need to craete a new column "Max10Runs" and apply the code which you gave here ? or how would it work .., Please help me here...

Comment: The step #"Grouped Rows" was created using the "Group By" option on the Transform tab. In the "Group By" pop-up, choose aggregation "All Rows" and OK. Then you need to go to the advanced editor (via the Home tab or the View tab) and enter the next step ("Max10Runs"). If you copy this step name after "in", then you can close the Advanced Editor and create the next step by expanding the "AllData" column - via the double-arrow button in the column header" - and select field "Runs".

Comment: Hello again @MarcelBeug 
Table,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(KustoQuery, each ([CompletionDateTime] <> null)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"EntityName"}, {{"GroupByEntity", each _, type table}})
    #"Max10Runs" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"AllData", each Table.MaxN(_, each [Runs], 10)}}),
    #"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Max10Runs, "AllData", {"Runs"}, {"Runs"})

This is how it is finally

Comment: Table,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(KustoQuery, each ([CompletionDateTime] <> null)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"EntityName"}, {{"GroupByEntity", each _, type table}}),
    #"Max10Runs" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Entity", each Table.MaxN(_, each [Runs], 10)}}),
    #"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Max10Runs, "Entity", {"Runs"}, {"Runs"})
in
    #"Expanded AllData"

Comment: Please help me here ..., Waiting for your kind reply

Comment: You named the grouped column "GroupByEntity"  instead of "AllData"